# ASP.NET MVC3 - Show SQL fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I am looking for something similar to [Bullet](http://railscasts.com/episodes/372-bullet) in Rails world, for ASP.NET MVC3.

To be specific, I am looking for a light-weight plugin to get all the SQL fired 
to load a web page, without having to mine logs.

I use FluentNhibernate, with SQL Server 2008 R2, on ASP.NET MVC3.

I have used [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com), and there is probably a way to add a plugin to check SQL as well. But I am looking for something much lighter.

Comment: If you don't mind paying for the small license fee, NHibernate Profiler is the way to go: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof. It has saved projects I've been involved in many times.

Comment: @simon whitehead  , why pay when both miniprofiler and glimpse give you the same results?

Comment: @AdamTuliper Just providing my experiences with NHProf. I haven't used the other two.. hence why I commented :)

Comment: @Simon - I already have NHProf license. I am looking for a plugin that can radiate this info on screen.

Comment: What do you perceive is heavy about Glimpse?

Comment: @nikmd23, Glimpse throws way too much information, than what I'd like in this instance. Although, it is configurable, in this case, I am looking for something specific, and in that context Glimpse does much more than what I want for now. I love Glimpse (and use it extensively), don't get me wrong, but I am looking to see if something lighter specifically for monitoring SQLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiniProfiler might be what you are looking for:  http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: MiniProfiler seems quite intrusive. I'm not sure that I want to scatter 'using' over my code, unless I'm missing something. Also, I see that MiniProfiler documentation seems to talk about EF, but not so much about NHibernate.

Comment: I use it with Nhibernate.  Also you don't need to scatter any usings.  You can use DI and AOP and hook it up in one place.

Comment: great, would it be possible to share a sample? I am using StructureMap for DI, so am hoping that this helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

Glimpse has plugins for several engines including entity framework.

Depending on your data access framework, you may want to try:

- [Glimpse for NHibernate](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Glimpse/3.3.1.4000)
- [Glimpse for RavenDB](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.RavenDb)
- [Glimpse for Entity Framework](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Ef)
- [Glimpse for PetaPoco](http://nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco.Glimpse)
- [Glimpse for LINQ2SQL](http://nuget.org/packages/FlexLabs.Glimpse.Linq2Sql)

Comment: Thanks Adam, I have been using Glimpse. Are you aware of any plugin for NHibernate queries?

Comment: I've added a list of Glimpse plugins for data access.